# Yii2 pass parameters to mail layout

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer

Is there any way to access your parameters within a mail layout when using the `Yii mailer` class? I can access `$model` from the view but not the layout.

```
<?php

        $params = array(
           "model" => $model
        );

        $message = Yii::$app->mailer->compose([
            'html' => $view.'Html',
            'text' => $view,
        ], $params)
        ->setFrom("me@placeholder.com")
        ->setTo($recipient)
        ->setSubject($subject);
?>
```

I know that for a standard web view you would set `yii\web\View::$params` to access variables in the layout but this doesn't appear to work for the mailer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just found out another way to set params to layout from controller :

```
// In your controler before send mail : 
Yii::$app->mailer->view->params['title'] = $title;

// In your layout
echo $this->params['title'];
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 5):

I'd do something similar to how you get breadcrumbs back to the view.

```
//In your view file, model was passed down via compose as you have it.
//this adds model element to the View object's params.
$this->params['model'] = $model; 

//In your layout
echo $this->params['model']->attribute;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It's unfortunate that I'll need to do this in every one of my email views but it's much better than having to duplicate header/footer html

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and now the params you pass can be directly called as variables in the email template:

```
// In controller
<?php
$params = [
    'username' => 'diegouser',
    'password' => 'supersecret',
];

Yii::$app->mailer->compose([
            'html' => 'layouts/' . $view . '-html',
            'text' => 'layouts/' . $view . '-text',
        ], $params)
        ->setFrom($mailFrom)
        ->setTo($emailTo)
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->send();
```

So you can just echo the variables in the layout:

```
<?php
// In email layout:
<?= $username ?>
<?= $password ?>
```